# Compiling sources with a non-default compiler

Tags: debian, compiling, make, c, linker

I need to implement an authentication scheme on an embedded device and require [gmp](https://gmplib.org/list-archives/gmp-announce/2014-March/000042.html) in order to perform large integer operations.
After downloading the sources they must be compiled with a proprietary version of compile tools in order to be able to statically link libraries(only one binary can be uploaded onto the controller at a time). 
After running configure the [following](http://paste.debian.net/277909/) make file is produced.

Running make with the proprietary compiler

```
make CC=/home/TI/ccsv5/tools/compiler/gcc-arm-none-eabi-4_7-2012q4/arm-none-eabi/bin/gcc
```

gives the following errors:

```
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/TI_workspace/gmp-6.0.0/mpn'
/bin/bash ../libtool --tag=CC   --mode=compile /home/TI/ccsv5/tools/compiler/gcc-arm-none-eabi-4_7-2012q4/arm-none-eabi/bin/gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -D__GMP_WITHIN_GMP -I.. -DOPERATION_`echo fib_table | sed 's/_$//'`    -O2 -pedantic -fomit-frame-pointer  -c -o fib_table.lo fib_table.c
libtool: compile:  /home/TI/ccsv5/tools/compiler/gcc-arm-none-eabi-4_7-2012q4/arm-none-eabi/bin/gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -D__GMP_WITHIN_GMP -I.. -DOPERATION_fib_table -O2 -pedantic -fomit-frame-pointer -c fib_table.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/fib_table.o
gcc: error trying to exec 'cc1': execvp: No such file or directory
make[2]: *** [fib_table.lo] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/TI_workspace/gmp-6.0.0/mpn'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/TI_workspace/gmp-6.0.0'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

cc1 is located in:

```
$ sudo find . -name cc1 -print
./ccsv5/tools/compiler/gcc-arm-none-eabi-4_7-2012q4/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.7.3/cc1
```

Is it possible to generate a makefile so that it uses the proprietary tool chain instead of the default one? If yes, how should it be configured?

Configure logs:

```
checking build system type... coreisbr-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi-strip... no
checking for strip... strip
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... mawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... no
checking ABI=standard
checking compiler arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi-gcc -marm -O2 -pedantic -fomit-frame-pointer ... no
checking compiler arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi-gcc -O2 -pedantic -fomit-frame-pointer ... no
checking compiler gcc -marm -O2 -pedantic -fomit-frame-pointer ... no
checking compiler gcc -O2 -pedantic -fomit-frame-pointer ... yes
checking whether ARM gcc unsigned division works... yes
checking for arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi-gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C99... -std=gnu99
checking for gcc -std=gnu99 option to accept ISO Standard C... (cached) -std=gnu99
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -std=gnu99 -E
checking build system compiler gcc -std=gnu99... yes
checking for build system preprocessor... gcc -std=gnu99 -E
checking for build system executable suffix... 
checking whether build system compiler is ANSI... yes
checking for build system compiler math library... -lm
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
using ABI="standard"
      CC="gcc -std=gnu99"
      CFLAGS="-O2 -pedantic -fomit-frame-pointer"
      CPPFLAGS=""
      MPN_PATH=" arm generic"
checking whether assembler supports --noexecstack option... yes
checking for arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi-ar... no
checking for ar... ar
checking for BSD- or MS-compatible name lister (nm)... no
checking for arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi-dumpbin... no
checking for arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi-link... no
checking for dumpbin... no
checking for link... link -dump
checking the name lister (nm) interface... BSD nm
checking for BSD- or MS-compatible name lister (nm)... /usr/bin/nm -B
checking the name lister (/usr/bin/nm -B) interface... (cached) BSD nm
checking how to print strings... printf
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
checking for fgrep... /bin/grep -F
checking for ld used by gcc -std=gnu99... /usr/bin/ld
checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... yes
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking the maximum length of command line arguments... 1572864
checking whether the shell understands some XSI constructs... yes
checking whether the shell understands "+="... yes
checking how to convert coreisbr-unknown-linux-gnu file names to arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi format... func_convert_file_noop
checking how to convert coreisbr-unknown-linux-gnu file names to toolchain format... func_convert_file_noop
checking for /usr/bin/ld option to reload object files... -r
checking for arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi-objdump... objdump
checking how to recognize dependent libraries... pass_all
checking for arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi-dlltool... dlltool
checking how to associate runtime and link libraries... printf %s\n
checking for arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi-ar... ar
checking for archiver @FILE support... @
checking for arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi-strip... strip
checking for arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi-ranlib... no
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking command to parse /usr/bin/nm -B output from gcc -std=gnu99 object... ok
checking for sysroot... no
checking for arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi-mt... no
checking for mt... mt
checking if mt is a manifest tool... no
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking for dlfcn.h... yes
checking for objdir... .libs
checking if gcc -std=gnu99 supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... no
checking for gcc -std=gnu99 option to produce PIC... -fPIC -DPIC
checking if gcc -std=gnu99 PIC flag -fPIC -DPIC works... yes
checking if gcc -std=gnu99 static flag -static works... yes
checking if gcc -std=gnu99 supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking if gcc -std=gnu99 supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
checking whether the gcc -std=gnu99 linker (/usr/bin/ld) supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether -lc should be explicitly linked in... no
checking dynamic linker characteristics... GNU/Linux ld.so
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build static libraries... yes
checking for ANSI C header files... (cached) yes
checking whether time.h and sys/time.h may both be included... yes
checking fcntl.h usability... yes
checking fcntl.h presence... yes
checking for fcntl.h... yes
checking float.h usability... yes
checking float.h presence... yes
checking for float.h... yes
checking invent.h usability... no
checking invent.h presence... no
checking for invent.h... no
checking langinfo.h usability... yes
checking langinfo.h presence... yes
checking for langinfo.h... yes
checking locale.h usability... yes
checking locale.h presence... yes
checking for locale.h... yes
checking nl_types.h usability... yes
checking nl_types.h presence... yes
checking for nl_types.h... yes
checking sys/attributes.h usability... no
checking sys/attributes.h presence... no
checking for sys/attributes.h... no
checking sys/iograph.h usability... no
checking sys/iograph.h presence... no
checking for sys/iograph.h... no
checking sys/mman.h usability... yes
checking sys/mman.h presence... yes
checking for sys/mman.h... yes
checking sys/param.h usability... yes
checking sys/param.h presence... yes
checking for sys/param.h... yes
checking sys/processor.h usability... no
checking sys/processor.h presence... no
checking for sys/processor.h... no
checking sys/pstat.h usability... no
checking sys/pstat.h presence... no
checking for sys/pstat.h... no
checking sys/sysinfo.h usability... yes
checking sys/sysinfo.h presence... yes
checking for sys/sysinfo.h... yes
checking sys/syssgi.h usability... no
checking sys/syssgi.h presence... no
checking for sys/syssgi.h... no
checking sys/systemcfg.h usability... no
checking sys/systemcfg.h presence... no
checking for sys/systemcfg.h... no
checking sys/time.h usability... yes
checking sys/time.h presence... yes
checking for sys/time.h... yes
checking sys/times.h usability... yes
checking sys/times.h presence... yes
checking for sys/times.h... yes
checking for sys/resource.h... yes
checking for sys/sysctl.h... yes
checking for machine/hal_sysinfo.h... no
checking whether fgetc is declared... yes
checking whether fscanf is declared... yes
checking whether optarg is declared... yes
checking whether ungetc is declared... yes
checking whether vfprintf is declared... yes
checking whether sys_errlist is declared... yes
checking whether sys_nerr is declared... yes
checking return type of signal handlers... void
checking for intmax_t... yes
checking for long double... yes
checking for long long... yes
checking for ptrdiff_t... yes
checking for quad_t... yes
checking for uint_least32_t... yes
checking for intptr_t... yes
checking for preprocessor stringizing operator... yes
checking for working volatile... yes
checking for C/C++ restrict keyword... __restrict
checking whether gcc __attribute__ ((const)) works... yes
checking whether gcc __attribute__ ((malloc)) works... yes
checking whether gcc __attribute__ ((mode (XX))) works... yes
checking whether gcc __attribute__ ((noreturn)) works... yes
checking for inline... inline
checking for cos in -lm... yes
checking for working alloca.h... yes
checking for alloca (via gmp-impl.h)... yes
checking how to allocate temporary memory... alloca
checking whether byte ordering is bigendian... no
checking format of `double' floating point... IEEE little endian
checking for alarm... yes
checking for attr_get... no
checking for clock... yes
checking for cputime... no
checking for getpagesize... yes
checking for getrusage... yes
checking for gettimeofday... yes
checking for getsysinfo... no
checking for localeconv... yes
checking for memset... yes
checking for mmap... yes
checking for mprotect... yes
checking for nl_langinfo... yes
checking for obstack_vprintf... yes
checking for popen... yes
checking for processor_info... no
checking for pstat_getprocessor... no
checking for raise... yes
checking for read_real_time... no
checking for sigaction... yes
checking for sigaltstack... yes
checking for sigstack... yes
checking for syssgi... no
checking for strchr... yes
checking for strerror... yes
checking for strnlen... yes
checking for strtol... yes
checking for strtoul... yes
checking for sysconf... yes
checking for sysctl... yes
checking for sysctlbyname... no
checking for times... yes
checking for library containing clock_gettime... none required
checking for vsnprintf... yes
checking whether vsnprintf works... yes
checking whether sscanf needs writable input... no
checking for struct pst_processor.psp_iticksperclktick... no
checking for suitable m4... m4
checking if m4wrap produces spurious output... no
checking how to switch to text section... .text
checking how to switch to data section... .data
checking for assembler label suffix... :
checking for assembler global directive... .globl
checking for assembler global directive attribute... 
checking if globals are prefixed by underscore... no
checking how to switch to read-only data section...     .section    .rodata
checking for assembler .type directive... .type $1,@$2
checking for assembler .size directive... .size $1,$2
checking for assembler local label prefix... .L
checking for assembler byte directive... .byte
checking how to define a 32-bit word... .long
checking if .align assembly directive is logarithmic... no
checking size of void *... 8
checking size of unsigned short... 2
checking size of unsigned... 4
checking size of unsigned long... 8
checking size of mp_limb_t... 8
configure: error: Oops, mp_limb_t is 64 bits, but the assembler code
in this configuration expects 32 bits.
```

Comment: Do you have a `GCC_EXEC_PREFIX` environment variable? If so, what is its value?

Comment: @Mark Plotnick. No, there is not.

Comment: What does `/home/TI/ccsv5/tools/compiler/gcc-arm-none-eabi-4_7-2012q4/arm-none-eabi/bin/gcc -print-prog-name=cc1` say?

Comment: @Stephen Kitt it says "cc1"

Answer (score 1):

According to GMP documentation https://gmplib.org/manual/Build-Options.html you should use those options:

> When cross-compiling, the system used for compiling is given by ‘--build’ and the system where the library will run is given by ‘--host’. For example when using a FreeBSD Athlon system to build GNU/Linux m68k binaries,
>
> ./configure --build=athlon-pc-freebsd3.5 --host=m68k-mac-linux-gnu

Comment: I cannot configure it to build the target for ARM. I get the same error as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24988221/gmp-compilation-for-ndk-error-oops-mp-limb-t-is-64-bits-but-the-assembler-cod

Comment: I downloaded the latest version of gmp (6.0.0a) and compiled it using arm gcc. I've used this command to configure: `./configure --host=arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi --with-sysroot=$SYSROOT` Everything works fine.

Comment: In my case the configuration fails with error: configure: error: Oops, mp_limb_t is 64 bits, but the assembler code
in this configuration expects 32 bits.

Comment: Looks like a problem with the toolchaine. If you can please post full log from configure.

Comment: I've updated the question with the logs.

Comment: Your toolchain is configured wrong. For cross-compilation you also need "cross-compiled" binutils. In your case `configure` script found only `arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi-gcc` compiler but all binutils ex. `as`, `ld`, `ar` are taken from system path `/usr/bin`. You've to add your toolchain path to system `PATH` variable and everything should be fine.